# uups: backup mssql server database file

Tags: sql-server

I must transfer one database from a first server to a second server. I received the 
Mydatababase.bak file from the first server, this file I copied to the second server in the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
 Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\Mydatabase_BACKUP.bak
```

In the RESTORE DATABASE Dialog of the MSSQL Server I receive the following error now while selecting my Backop file

```
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL      
     Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MyDatabase_Bak.bak 
    : Family count:2 : Missing family sequence number :1
```

What does the error mean? What information is missing now ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224745/any-other-solutions-for-sqls-the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889197/sql-server-restoring-back-up-error

Comment: found the answer now, thanks