# Issue with restoring the database in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

When I try to restore the DB in Sql Server I am getting the following error message:

> Backup mediaset is not complete. Family count:2. Missing family
>   sequence number :1

I googled for this error and found that the backup of the database wrote its data to two files.

But how can I find those files? I have already dropped the database. I have only  abackup copy of that particular DB.

Comment: See if `RESTORE HEADERONLY` gives you more information.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889197/sql-server-restoring-back-up-error may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information in msdb database even after dropping a database.
please run below query to get the list of all the backup performed on a SQL instance-

```
select bs.name,bs.backup_size,  bs.database_name , bs.backup_start_date , bm.physical_device_name  
from msdb.dbo.backupset bs
join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bm
on bs.media_set_id  = bs.media_set_id
ORDER BY bs.backup_start_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but i dont find any details related to the dropped DB with the query you had provided.

Comment: Then you have learned a painful lesson - if you cannot find a similar file by searching the volume where you found the first file, you are doomed.